# Why is my foreign key getting an invalid identifier?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting an error when trying to create my student table. I'm getting an error with the foreign key. It states that I have an invalid identifier but I double checked the studtype table to make sure, and I don't see a difference. Any help will be appreciated.

**Statements**

```
 CREATE TABLE STUDENT
    (STUDID VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
     STUDNAME VARCHAR2(30),
     STUDADDRESS VARCHAR2(30),
     STUDTELNO VARCHAR2(17),
     CONSTRAINT PKSTUD PRIMARY KEY(STUDID),
     CONSTRAINT FKSTYPE FOREIGN KEY(STUDTYPE) REFERENCES STUDTYPE(STUDTYPE) ON     DELETE CASCADE));
```

Error:ORA-00904: "STUDTYPE": invalid identifier

```
CREATE TABLE STUDTYPE
(STUDTYPE VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PKSTYPE PRIMARY KEY(STUDTYPE));
```

Comment: You don't have a column in `STUDENT` named `STUDTYPE`.  The constraint just creates the constraint, not the column,  You have to define the column separately.

Comment: Also be careful of using `ON DELETE CASCADE`. What that means is if you delete a student type all students with that type are also deleted silently.

Comment: i cant believe i made this stupid mistake thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should have a STUDTYPE column in Student table. So your create script for student table should be as follows

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT
    (STUDID VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
     STUDTYPE VARCHAR2(30),
     STUDNAME VARCHAR2(30),
     STUDADDRESS VARCHAR2(30),
     STUDTELNO VARCHAR2(17),
     CONSTRAINT PKSTUD PRIMARY KEY(STUDID),
     CONSTRAINT FKSTYPE FOREIGN KEY(STUDTYPE) REFERENCES STUDTYPE(STUDTYPE) ON     DELETE CASCADE));
```